# Classic ASP with XML - Null Value

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I have the following classic ASP code:

```
Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    URL="The link to the XML source goes here"
    objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", URL, false
    objXMLHTTP.Send

    strHTML = objXMLHTTP.responseText

    'Load the XML File
    Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objXML.async = False
    objXML.loadXML(strHTML)

    Set objLst = objXML.getElementsByTagName("result")

strSearchCity = objLst(0).getElementsByTagName("adminArea5")(0).firstchild.nodeValue
strSearchState = objLst(0).getElementsByTagName("adminArea3")(0).firstchild.nodeValue
```

Here is a snip-it of the XML that works fine:

```
<response>
<info>
</info>
<results>
   <result>
      <providedLocation>
         <location>chicago, il</location>
      </providedLocation>
      <locations>
         <location>
             <adminArea5 type="City">Chicago</adminArea5>
             <adminArea3 type="State">IL</adminArea3>
             <adminArea4 type="County">Cook County</adminArea4>
         </location>
      </locations>
   </result>
</results>
</response>
```

However, if one of these comes back null, I get an error.

```
<location>
    <adminArea5 type="City">Washington</adminArea5>
    <adminArea3 type="State"/>
</location>
```

I apologize, as I'm sure this will be easy, but how do I prevent the error from occuring? Do I check to see if the value is null? Do I grab the values in a different way?

Thank you.

Rick

Answer (score 0):

`firstChild.nodeValue` requires the `firstChild` property to be not-null, because `null` doesn't have `nodeValue` property.

The simpler way to avoid that error is to use `innerText` instead of `firstChild.nodeValue` :

```
strSearchState = objLst(0).getElementsByTagName("adminArea3")(0).innerText
```

Comment: Thank you. However, that gives me an error `Object doesn't support this property or method: 'innerText'`

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out.  I used `Text` rather than `innerText` and that worked great. Thank you for leading me in the right direction.